# how to escape JavaScript code in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I have some `addHtml` JavaScript function in my JS code. I wonder how to escape HTML/JS code properly. Basically, what I am trying right now is:

```
addHtml("<a onclick=\"alert(\\\"Hello from JS\\\")\">click me</a>")
```

However, that doesn't work. It adds the `a` element but it doesn't do anything when I click it.

I don't want to replace all `"` by `'` as a workaround. (If I do, it works.)

Comment: Why 3 backslashses? Just put one backslash before each double quote inside your method "\

Comment: One wonders why you are using string literals to add an HTML element to the page instead of creating an element in the dom and attaching an event to it?

Comment: @Marko: Then it would not be valid HTML.

Comment: @Darko: This is just for testing and I reduced the testcase to put it here on SO. Even if I would solve this particular task in a way where I go around the problem, I would still not have solved the problem itself because I will need it elsewhere.

Comment: You say it adds the a element. does the onclick get put onto that element with nothing in it? or is the onclick missing all together?

Comment: Did you try using something like Firebug and seeing what the error was that you were getting?

Comment: @Shaded, Jeff: Any easy way to check? It is a QWebView via PyQt (and no way right now to test it in a 'real' browser).

Comment: Well either the alert value or the onclick needs to have a single quote because the onclick's quotes will interfere with alerts quotes. You can't do this in plain HTML either, let alone javascript. You're trying to do <a onclick="alert("Hello from Js")">click me</a> which will fail in plain HTML

Comment: @Marko: I came up with this solution now: http://pastebin.com/QQig9y82 It seems to work. Do you know any case where it does not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wonder how to escape HTML/JS code properly.

To insert string content into an HTML event handler attribute:

(1) Encode it as a JavaScript string literal:

```
alert("Hello \"world\"");
```

(2) Encode the complete JavaScript statement as HTML:

```
<a onclick="alert(&quot;Hello \&quot;world\&quot;&quot;">foo</a>
```

And since you seem to be including *that* HTML inside a JavaScript string literal again, you have to JS-encode it *again*:

```
html= "<a onclick=\"alert(&quot;Hello \\&quot;world\\&quot;&quot;\">foo<\/a>";
```

Notice the double-backslashes and also the `<\/`, which is necessary to avoid a `</` sequence in a `<script>` block, which would otherwise be invalid and might break.

You can make this less bad for yourself by mixing single and double quotes to cut down on the amount of double-escaping going on, but you can't solve it for the general case; there are many other characters that will cause problems.

All this escaping horror is another good reason to **avoid inline event handler attributes**. Slinging strings full of HTML around sucks. Use DOM-style methods, assigning event handlers directly from JavaScript instead:

```
var a= document.createElement('a');
a.onclick= function() {
    alert('Hello from normal JS with no extra escaping!');
};
```

Comment: Great answer, bobince.  I basically came up with my answer of `addHtml("<a onclick=\"alert(&quot;Hello from JS&quot;)\">click me</a>");` by trial and error, but this makes clear *why* it worked.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be

```
addHtml('<a onclick="alert(\'Hello from JS\')">click me</a>')
```

I typically use single quotes in Javascript strings, and double quotes in HTML attributes.  I think it's a good rule to follow.

Comment: I may want to use more complex JS code snippets there and I want to escape it in a general way that it always works. Just replacing all `"` by `'` would probably not work in all cases.

Comment: You would replace all ' with \'

Comment: And how would I replace the `"` if there are any in the JS code? What if I want to put the full `addHtml(...)` again as the onclick code? (I need a general solution which works for just any code.)

Comment: The odds are pointing to the idea that you have made a poor design decision.

Comment: I found, when trying to solve exactly this problem, that on an older version of FireFox that you had to be careful which way around you did the quotes: double inside single, or single inside double? The former didn't always work! Avoiding the need to handle this is better.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
addHtml("<a onclick=\"alert(&quot;Hello from JS&quot;)\">click me</a>");
```

It worked when I tested in Firefox, at any rate.

Comment: Ah thanks, so just replacing all `"` by `&quot;` and it will always work? Well, at least all cases I have tested so far. And tested in Webkit.

Comment: I came up with this final solution now (which does exactly that): http://pastebin.com/QQig9y82

Answer (score 1):

```
addHtml("<a onclick='alert(\"Hello from JS\")'>click me</a>")
```

Comment: That's right it's not a general solution, it's just a solution to the string you provided. I think you have to escape the string before passing it to the function.

Comment: Yes, that was what my question is about. :) How do I escape the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably this...

As your code is now, it will add this to the HTML

```
<a onclick="alert("Hello from Javascript")"></a>
```

This is assuming the escape slashes will all be removed properly.

The problem is that the alert can't handle the " inside it... you'll have to change those quotes to single quotes.

```
addHtml("<a onclick=\"alert(\\\'Hello from JS\\\')\">click me</a>")
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

What does the final HTML rendered in the browser look like ? I think the three slashes might be causing an issue .

Comment: Yes it does not work, that is what the question is all about. :)